# C# RSA Encrypt and Decrypt using Custom Keypairs

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

i need to Decrypt a data using a Custom RSA Keypair that is genereated by a tool.
But when i try to import the private key i get "Incorrect Data" exeption. Any idea?

```
private static RSAParameters publicKey;
private static RSAParameters privateKey;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider encryptionProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    encryptionProvider.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    publicKey = encryptionProvider.ExportParameters(false);
    privateKey = encryptionProvider.ExportParameters(true);

    byte[] publicKeyArray =
    {
        0x30, 0x81, 0x9f, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
        0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x81, 0x8d, 0x00, 0x30, 0x81, 0x89, 0x02, 0x81, 0x81, 0x00, 0xb8, 0x75, 0x59,
        0x9b, 0x89, 0xaa, 0xf7, 0x58, 0x70, 0xf0, 0xac, 0x84, 0x7d, 0xb3, 0xb2, 0x65, 0x86, 0x14, 0xc3,
        0x64, 0x7c, 0xda, 0x9b, 0x6b, 0x4c, 0xa8, 0x61, 0xca, 0x60, 0x7a, 0xbd, 0x06, 0x38, 0x1d, 0xe7,
        0xa1, 0x7a, 0x76, 0x0d, 0xf0, 0xde, 0x43, 0xa1, 0xc9, 0x4e, 0x13, 0x43, 0x31, 0xf0, 0x85, 0x95,
        0xc2, 0x1d, 0x83, 0xe5, 0xd2, 0x04, 0xda, 0xa5, 0x75, 0x44, 0xa4, 0xbd, 0x6b, 0x8c, 0x22, 0x4b,
        0xf7, 0xf6, 0x1c, 0x95, 0x26, 0x58, 0x59, 0x95, 0x24, 0xa9, 0xbf, 0x06, 0xa8, 0xc4, 0x6e, 0xd3,
        0x32, 0x67, 0x2d, 0x31, 0xa2, 0xbc, 0x4d, 0x66, 0xbd, 0xfa, 0xac, 0x5a, 0xd1, 0xf3, 0x0d, 0xb9,
        0x89, 0x2f, 0x20, 0x84, 0x27, 0xcf, 0xe2, 0x9d, 0x6b, 0xb2, 0xc1, 0x31, 0x06, 0x4d, 0xfd, 0x82,
        0x4a, 0x0a, 0x19, 0x76, 0x80, 0xb4, 0x49, 0x6c, 0x71, 0xdd, 0xd4, 0x98, 0x7f, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01,
        0x00, 0x01,
    };

    byte[] privateKeyArray =
    {
        0x30, 0x82, 0x02, 0x5c, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x81, 0x81, 0x00, 0xb8, 0x75, 0x59, 0x9b, 0x89,
        0xaa, 0xf7, 0x58, 0x70, 0xf0, 0xac, 0x84, 0x7d, 0xb3, 0xb2, 0x65, 0x86, 0x14, 0xc3, 0x64, 0x7c,
        0xda, 0x9b, 0x6b, 0x4c, 0xa8, 0x61, 0xca, 0x60, 0x7a, 0xbd, 0x06, 0x38, 0x1d, 0xe7, 0xa1, 0x7a,
        0x76, 0x0d, 0xf0, 0xde, 0x43, 0xa1, 0xc9, 0x4e, 0x13, 0x43, 0x31, 0xf0, 0x85, 0x95, 0xc2, 0x1d,
        0x83, 0xe5, 0xd2, 0x04, 0xda, 0xa5, 0x75, 0x44, 0xa4, 0xbd, 0x6b, 0x8c, 0x22, 0x4b, 0xf7, 0xf6,
        0x1c, 0x95, 0x26, 0x58, 0x59, 0x95, 0x24, 0xa9, 0xbf, 0x06, 0xa8, 0xc4, 0x6e, 0xd3, 0x32, 0x67,
        0x2d, 0x31, 0xa2, 0xbc, 0x4d, 0x66, 0xbd, 0xfa, 0xac, 0x5a, 0xd1, 0xf3, 0x0d, 0xb9, 0x89, 0x2f,
        0x20, 0x84, 0x27, 0xcf, 0xe2, 0x9d, 0x6b, 0xb2, 0xc1, 0x31, 0x06, 0x4d, 0xfd, 0x82, 0x4a, 0x0a,
        0x19, 0x76, 0x80, 0xb4, 0x49, 0x6c, 0x71, 0xdd, 0xd4, 0x98, 0x7f, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01,
        0x02, 0x81, 0x80, 0x19, 0x72, 0x11, 0x73, 0x19, 0x61, 0xfc, 0xf9, 0x0b, 0x00, 0xc8, 0x6b, 0xb1,
        0x2e, 0x26, 0xd5, 0x46, 0x7d, 0x25, 0x6f, 0x29, 0x4c, 0xbc, 0x2a, 0x93, 0x1f, 0xef, 0x4d, 0x8c,
        0x52, 0xf7, 0x87, 0x1c, 0xc5, 0x53, 0x52, 0x12, 0xa3, 0x52, 0x77, 0xab, 0x26, 0xf2, 0x9c, 0x8d,
        0xd4, 0x03, 0xc2, 0xfc, 0x86, 0x66, 0x60, 0x54, 0x28, 0xab, 0xd2, 0xcb, 0x04, 0xa1, 0x2a, 0x8a,
        0x2b, 0x9c, 0xf8, 0x35, 0xc8, 0x4a, 0x99, 0xdf, 0x86, 0xab, 0x7a, 0x2e, 0x92, 0x2c, 0xd6, 0xf8,
        0xcd, 0x99, 0xa6, 0xca, 0xc9, 0x95, 0x6c, 0x91, 0xd4, 0x7f, 0x01, 0x98, 0x62, 0x28, 0x38, 0x2b,
        0x8b, 0xc2, 0x29, 0x2c, 0x9b, 0xe0, 0xf1, 0x2c, 0x84, 0x76, 0xa0, 0x55, 0xd0, 0x29, 0x53, 0xac,
        0x8f, 0xe5, 0xb1, 0x99, 0xc2, 0x53, 0x44, 0xb0, 0x62, 0x41, 0x26, 0x85, 0x6e, 0xfc, 0xfc, 0x29,
        0x4d, 0x8b, 0xd1, 0x02, 0x41, 0x00, 0xdc, 0xe6, 0x21, 0x58, 0xff, 0x95, 0xcd, 0xc7, 0x26, 0xa3,
        0xd5, 0xcf, 0x9b, 0x90, 0x96, 0xfd, 0x7c, 0x37, 0x23, 0xcf, 0xd8, 0x1a, 0x9a, 0x7d, 0x64, 0x29,
        0x05, 0x75, 0x6b, 0x7a, 0x4b, 0xf2, 0x42, 0xf7, 0x34, 0xd5, 0x68, 0x9a, 0xc7, 0xb5, 0x6f, 0xc6,
        0xc0, 0xac, 0x18, 0xaa, 0xba, 0xcd, 0xe2, 0x1a, 0xa5, 0xa2, 0xa5, 0x44, 0x57, 0xf4, 0x50, 0x5c,
        0xad, 0x88, 0x16, 0x7d, 0x06, 0xdb, 0x02, 0x41, 0x00, 0xd5, 0xc4, 0xde, 0x1f, 0xbe, 0x29, 0x49,
        0x7d, 0x87, 0x7a, 0xdd, 0xa2, 0xdc, 0x40, 0xad, 0x93, 0xa2, 0x84, 0x82, 0xdd, 0xfb, 0xb8, 0x9d,
        0x5a, 0xa2, 0x65, 0x1d, 0x03, 0x35, 0x9f, 0x80, 0x0e, 0x85, 0x39, 0x87, 0xbf, 0xdf, 0x5b, 0x57,
        0x9e, 0x10, 0x95, 0x01, 0x78, 0x5c, 0x59, 0xdd, 0xdf, 0x7c, 0x41, 0x55, 0x9c, 0xb3, 0x39, 0x3d,
        0xa3, 0x06, 0xe8, 0xd8, 0x58, 0xbb, 0xc2, 0x6c, 0x2d, 0x02, 0x40, 0x05, 0xa0, 0xff, 0x9c, 0x8a,
        0xf6, 0xc0, 0x45, 0xa0, 0xe0, 0x6f, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x6c, 0x78, 0xcc, 0x80, 0xcb, 0xce, 0xe7, 0xce,
        0xf3, 0xee, 0x97, 0xdf, 0x63, 0x84, 0x36, 0x17, 0xc5, 0x08, 0x06, 0x66, 0x5a, 0x72, 0x48, 0x35,
        0xe0, 0x2b, 0xd2, 0x9d, 0xc4, 0x8c, 0xc8, 0x55, 0xe0, 0x93, 0xde, 0x07, 0x32, 0xf2, 0xa1, 0x90,
        0x60, 0x8b, 0x75, 0x38, 0x4f, 0x04, 0x45, 0x01, 0x7d, 0xb2, 0x1d, 0x02, 0x40, 0x27, 0x11, 0x10,
        0x6b, 0x0a, 0xac, 0xae, 0xf2, 0x92, 0xf4, 0xe0, 0x56, 0x68, 0x1c, 0x25, 0xdc, 0xaa, 0x41, 0xbf,
        0x4c, 0xe4, 0x38, 0xec, 0x00, 0xe9, 0x56, 0xc3, 0x43, 0x97, 0xe4, 0x2b, 0x59, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xf4,
        0x93, 0x1b, 0x35, 0xad, 0x40, 0x84, 0xd5, 0x46, 0x6c, 0x81, 0xac, 0x26, 0xc1, 0x36, 0x0b, 0x16,
        0xa3, 0x49, 0x99, 0xb7, 0x6a, 0xf8, 0xd3, 0x4a, 0xde, 0x84, 0x89, 0xd6, 0x8d, 0x02, 0x41, 0x00,
        0xa0, 0x44, 0xca, 0x9e, 0xfd, 0xbe, 0x3a, 0x48, 0x6a, 0xf8, 0xc0, 0x1b, 0x1f, 0x11, 0x35, 0x25,
        0x35, 0x98, 0xca, 0x5d, 0x1e, 0x14, 0xc1, 0xf9, 0xa6, 0x25, 0x4a, 0xf4, 0x5c, 0x8f, 0xa3, 0xef,
        0xa0, 0xe5, 0x92, 0xfb, 0x11, 0x43, 0x4b, 0x00, 0xd7, 0xe5, 0x15, 0x9c, 0x20, 0xb3, 0x0a, 0x56,
        0x83, 0x8b, 0x09, 0x51, 0xb6, 0x71, 0x82, 0x87, 0x00, 0xc7, 0x4b, 0xf9, 0xe0, 0xf7, 0xe3, 0x79,
    };

    publicKey.Modulus = publicKeyArray;
    privateKey.Modulus = privateKeyArray;

    encryptionProvider.ImportParameters(publicKey);
    encryptionProvider.ImportParameters(privateKey);
}
```

BTW the public key seems to be working fine, if i remove the "encryptionProvider.ImportParameters(privateKey)", i can Encrypt
some data sucessfull.

Comment: For debugging sake are you able to encrypt and decrypt fresh content using what you have now and let me know

Comment: I can encrypt sucessfull, but i can't decrypt because i get a exeption when triying to import the private key from the array

Comment: Have you tried generating your own key and testing that? Just to eliminate the possibility of the key being bad.

Comment: Nope, but i thinks that the keys is generated correctly because the same software that generate the keypairs use it. And it can encrypt and Decrypt sucessfull. I'am implementing a Web API for this software, so i have to use the keypairs generated by it.

Comment: Your byte arrays are the DER encoding of some standard ASN.1 formats (X509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo and PKCS1 RSAPrivateKey), but .NET does have any methods just yet to read them in. The Bouncycastle C# library has such methods however.

Comment: This is my first time working with RSA (And with encryption too), so if you could show me an example I would be very grateful.